# SolrJ Embedded Server Spring Config No longer working

Tags: spring, spring-data, solrj

I have this spring config that I used in my tests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr-1.0.xsd">

  <solr:embedded-solr-server id="tgySolrServer" solrHome="target/test-classes" />
</beans>
```

throwing now this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)V
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.createPathConfiguredSolrServer(EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.initSolrServer(EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean.java:36)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 40 more
```

I currently have Solr 4.5.0 and spring-data-solr 1.0.0-RELEASE. What should I do to use the embedded server in my tests?

Comment: none so far. but I haven't dug farther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now

we need to add following dependency and repository to `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

That's it !!!